# How to disable history/url redirect in navigation bar in grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have created a small application in grails. It's working fine but when I copy/paste url in navigation bar, it is directly redirecting to a particular page. How to give security for that?

Comment: Wow, before I edited, you just copy/paste 3 times your question with a "plz help me"? Please read this before any other move on this site : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what is expected behavior?